# iOS: self.view.bounds does not fill the whole window

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, calayer, iphone-4

I am doing some simple testing of adding CALayer to a UIView. In my main controller class of an iPhone 4 app, I implemented the `viewDidLoad` method as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    CALayer* ca = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [ca setBounds:self.view.bounds];

    [ca setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:ca];
}
```

The blue background only occupy 1/4 of the screen.

[image]

I wonder if it is because I did not take retina display into consideration? What is the best practice in this situation?

---

Added these debug messages:

```
NSLog(@"frame w:%f h:%f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"bounds w:%f h:%f", self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Output:

```
frame w:320.000000 h:460.000000
bounds w:320.000000 h:460.000000
```

Comment: What is the value of `self.view.frame`? Can you verify.

Comment: @Deepak: It is {width:320, height:460}. Added the debug output to the question itself too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setContentsScale` has no effect

```
  [ca setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
```

However, if I use

```
  [ca setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

it works.

Comment: +1 Good one! With `position` being zero, rest of the contents went off screen.

Comment: @Deepak: I see! So CALayer positions itself based on the position/anchor point, which is at the center point of the bounds. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You figured it out. I just interpreted. :)